# How do I create a class that will order children?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a class that will order all the children of an GameObject. So I have a GameObject, which contains about 50 children. Now I'm creating a new object that makes him a kid for this gameobject. Now, in this child, I add 3 children from the main gameobject. Below is the code I wrote, but something is wrong.

```
private GameObject CloneObject;
private int index = 0;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
void Start()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        index++;

        if (index == 3)
        {
            CloneObject = new GameObject("ob");
            CloneObject.transform.parent = transform;
            transform.GetChild(i).transform.parent = CloneObject.transform;
            index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply us with what exactly is going wrong? An error or what is or isn't happening?

Comment: This is hard to understand, please consider adding more information to your question

Comment: Observable Pattern??

Comment: "order children"? how do you mean order them, order as in give instruction or order as in sort?

Comment: well, I apologize, so I'm just here and I do not know the rules yet

Comment: so  3 children must make children of the created object, and again three other children for the second object created, and so on

Comment: By calling `CloneObject.transform.parent = transform;` it will be considered as a child itself. I would do the reparenting in a separate step after all children are assigned, for example by storing them in a temporary list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this loop does is that it creates (int)(transform.childCount / 3) GameObjects, each with one child. What you need is this I suppose:

```
CloneObject = new GameObject("ob");
for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
{
    index++;

    CloneObject.transform.parent = transform;
    transform.GetChild(i).transform.parent = CloneObject.transform;

    if (index == 3)
    {
        CloneObject = new GameObject("ob");
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

You add first 3 child objects to the current GameObject and then create a new one.